# How to get two div tags without space in between them?

Tags: css, html, jsp

i want to have a two lines of as footer as

[image]

When iam using two div tags foe first row and second row i am getting a space and it is showing a s below

[image]

```html
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; text-align: left;">AAAA</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: right;">CCCC</p>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; text-align: left;">DDDD</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">EEEE</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: right;">FFFF</p>
</div>
```

Comment: space or line break in current case?

Comment: no i dont have any space

Comment: show us the html & css code

Comment: please add a code snippet or jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using Block tag 'p' which include auto margin please remove that and see space will reduce

```html
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; text-align: left;margin:0px">AAAA</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;margin:0px">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: right;margin:0px">CCCC</p>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; text-align: left;margin:0px">DDDD</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;margin:0px">EEEE</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: right;margin:0px">FFFF</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each 'p' element. The margins can be modified with CSS (with the margin properties).
>   So you have to remove margins of 'p' tag with css

```css
p {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; text-align: left;">AAAA</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: right;">CCCC</p>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; text-align: left;">DDDD</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">EEEE</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: right;">FFFF</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```html
<div style="width:100%; color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left;margin: 0 0 0 0; width: 34%; text-align: left;">AAAA</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%;margin: 0 0 0 0; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%;margin: 0 0 0 0; text-align: right;">CCCC</p>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; color:#4682b4;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; margin: 0 0 0 0;text-align: left;">DDDD</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%;margin: 0 0 0 0; text-align: center;">EEEE</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%;margin: 0 0 0 0; text-align: right;">FFFF</p>
</div>
```